# Android - multithreading

Tags: android, multithreading, canvas

Creating a simple game on android.
I have to draw random pictures in random places of canvas.

The problem is with appearing pictures and disappearing them.
Each picture should disappear in say 5 seconds (during this time moving hero will have to catch them).

I tried to draw a pictures in separate thread, but it is not working.

On this piece of code I want tmpBitmap to appear and disappear in 5 seconds.
(during this time main thread surely should solve other tasks)
How to do it corectly?

```
public class Drawing extends View implements OnTouchListener {

    Bitmap ball;
    static Canvas myCanvas;
    static Bitmap tmpBitmap;

    public Drawing(Context context) {
        super(context);
        /// ... . .. 

        tmpBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.strawberry);

        setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        myCanvas = canvas;

        // . .. . . . 

        /// Trying to run drawing in separate thread and disappear in 5 sec.

        MyThread t1 = new MyThread ();
        t1.start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        t1.interrupt();

        invalidate();
    }
    // ....

}


public class MyThread extends Thread {

    public void run() {

        while(!currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            Drawing.myCanvas.drawBitmap(Drawing.tmpBitmap, 100, 100, null);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean appear and disappear? using `canvas.drawColor()`?

Comment: What is the Problem? Are the pictures not dissapearing or is the main thread blocking or if you get an Exception add the stack trace.

Comment: You don't need a thread (you're also using it wrong and make the main thread wait). You need to schedule code to be executed in the future but in the main thread! That's what [`Handler#???Delayed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) is for. Each `View` has btw one you can use: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29

Comment: I mean a bitmap should be drawn. And in 5 seconds it must not be on canvas. If the hero gets to this place during 5 seconds - it will receive points. If he gets in that place after 5 sec. It will not receive points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My goodnes, why on earth you block thread for 5 secs... ? And why you are invalidating inside onDraw? Your game will not be too smooth :P You should do something like:

```
long startTime;

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    myCanvas = canvas;

    // . .. . . . 

    /// Trying to run drawing in separate thread and disappear in 5 sec.

    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime >= 5000) {
        // toggle your bitmap
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    {
}
```

Or, which will be better, you should use [ScheduledThreadExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). In your view constructor you should launch such executor with fixed rate. Runned task should switch flag that will say if btmap should be drown.

```
boolean drawBitmap;

public Drawing(Context context) {
    super(context);
    /// ... . .. 

    tmpBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.strawberry);

    setOnTouchListener(this);
    // run task here that will switch flag
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    myCanvas = canvas;

    // . .. . . . 

    if (drawBitmap) {
        // draw your bitmap here
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you also help with this timer please. Say bitmap shoul appear in 4 sec. after beginning, then be available within 5 seconds and then disappear.   After 4 seconds appear again etc.   I use next code in onDraw:        if  (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime >=4000) {
   drawBitmap = true;
  }
   
  if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime >= 9000) {
   drawBitmap = false;
   startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }
  if (drawBitmap) {
   canvas.drawBitmap(tmpBitmap, 100, 100, p);
  }   What's wrong? (it's not working)

Comment: Also I did not understand why you uset oppisite: (startTime - System.currentTimeMillis() >= 5000). As far as I understand it will never happened. Thanks.

Comment: That is my mistake, thanks for pointing this out. I have edited my post. What does it mean that it does not work?

Comment: it's ok. But my code is still not working. What is wrong here? if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime >=4000) { drawBitmap = true; } if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime >= 9000) { drawBitmap = false; startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); } if (drawBitmap) { canvas.drawBitmap(tmpBitmap, 100, 100, p); }

Comment: Everything is nice now. Thank you again